# Chat/conversation history, entity relationship diagram

Tags: postgresql, database-design, erd, database-diagrams

Totally aware that there are very similar questions, went through each of them, but those are pretty simple/basic solutions from where i took some things and ideas to create below entity relationship diagram, according to my needs. What i'm up to is to create database schema (**postgresql**) for chat/conversation history, where i need to support couple of tricky things, such as:

1. Chat have a name and initial creator (`customer_id`)
2. Chat message created by `customer_id` can either be a plain text message or a file, while
   those two are sharing some of the columns, but in a sense those are
   different in a way that file can have `file_name`, `file_mime_type`,
   `external_path` like location where it is saved (e.g file system),
   and file can be marked as being `relevant` or not, by anybody in
   conversation. Due to many differences between the two, to me at least, seems
   more natural to divide the two and to have "common parent" table, `chat_lines`. Other approach would be to have single table with many NULL values or so. Highly interested to see your opinion about it.
3. One of the biggest worries that i have is that chat participant being
   able to `reply_to` existing chat line or start a thread on existing
   chat line. I have no better idea than to make `chat_lines` table having two separate
   references to itself. I do not see any better way of how to model threads and replies.
4. Each message can be `seen` by anybody in discussion, hence
   introducing `seens` table. Not quite sure is `seens` correct english
   word.
5. Finally anybody in conversation/chat can react to each `chat line`,
   like `thumb up`, `thumb down`, no more than that, so ENUM seems like
   a nice approach.

After hours and hours of thinking i came to this:

[image]

One of the worries here for me is that `chat lines` table have become like a `God table`, everything is concentrated around that table and probably every future table will be related to it. Further, each `SELECT` query must `JOIN` literally everything in order to rebuild chat history. Worrying about performances a lot, would expect that `chat_lines` table will become huge over time, just imagine that one single chat between 5 to 10 participants can have around 1k-5k chat lines, with few file uploads along the way. Looking for proper `indexes` on those table. Each `SELECT` query that i can imagine now will be probably using heavily `chat name`, `customer ids` (like participants of the chat). So thinking to create some `indexes` on those.

Of course, whatever participant can search for mentioned things. When it comes to plain text messages, seems like way to go is postgresql `tsvector` against `text` column in `messages` table. Participant will be able to search against `file_name` when it comes to file uploads, so seems reasonable to have index on `file_name` in `files` table.

Please sorry for a little bit "opinionated question", highly interested in your opinion about how much this solution will scale in the future, would highly appreciated any advice what could be changed. Any other idea how replies and threads could be modeled? Where you would add indexes? Whatever i do, i guess database partions based on something from this schema should be created in future when data starts to grow very much.

Comment: Readability note: please reserve `monospace` for actual identifiers / keywords. Use **bold** or *italics* for emphasis / highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some loose opinions which may be useful but may be completely off:

- The model looks OK and should be scalable as far as I can tell.
- Relational model (3NF) is the king of storage size, and data consistency. It's not the king of "easy querying". See `customer_id` note below.
- In actual long term business, maintainability is often more important than performance.
- Don't worry about partitioning too soon. You may never see this first 0.5 TB of customer data in your database. But consider making `customer_id` the part of PK in all tables if this is going to be a multi-tenant app. It will make scaling up (think: sharding / separating tenants) easier.
- The `thread` ID might be as well synonymous to `chat_lines`.`id` of top level item.
- tsearch is OK, but for large scale, fancy fulltext search you might need to employ some outside tools like ElasticSearch / Sphinx / etc.

Comment: @fliprem thank you on very nice answer. I tend to have everything in 1NF, 2NF, 3NF, which above should be. Totally aware that sometimes denormalisation is the way to go.
This will be one service of microservices system architecture. Can you just share some light what do you mean by following:
"The thread ID might be as well synonymous to chat_lines.id of top level item."

Comment: @Srle each thread begins with a chat_line, so it's disputable if you actually want a separate identifier for the thread object

Comment: how then to keep track which chat_line belongs to what thread? very similar to reply_to. Both of them `thread` and `reply_to` are referencing same table `chat_line`

Comment: ah yes that makes sense. thanks for explaining